# How to convert data separated pipe to rows?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, t-sql, sql-server-2016, table

I work on `sql server 2017` I have table name `#countriesData` data as below

my issue here How to convert `countries column`  data separated `pipe` to rows .

meaning every `rev and company and year` will have only one `country` per row .

```
   create table #countriesData
 (
 company int,
 [Year] int,
 rev  int,
 countries varchar(500)
 )
 insert into #countriesData(company,[Year],rev,countries)
 values
 (12011,2010,121,'Egypt|France|America'),
 (12011,2011,121,'Egypt|Canda|America'),
 (12011,2012,121,'China|Canda|America'),
 (12099,2010,121,'SaudiArabia|France|America'),
 (12099,2011,121,'Egypt|Canda|German'),
 (12099,2012,121, 'China|Italy|America')
```

my expected result will be as below :
[image: picture for pipe separated rows]

suppose i have two columns have pipe
so how to modify query to handle two columns have pipe on same time

```
 create table #countriesData
 (
 company int,
 [Year] int,
 rev  int,
 countries varchar(500),
 countries1 varchar(500)
 )
 insert into #countriesData(company,[Year],rev,countries,countries2)
 values
 (12011,2010,121,'Egypt|France|America','India|France|America'),
 (12011,2011,121,'Egypt|Canda|America','India|Indonisya|America'),
 (12011,2012,121,'China|Canda|America','Pakistan|Indonisya|America'),
 (12099,2010,121,'SaudiArabia|France|America','Pakistan|sryia|America'),
 (12099,2011,121,'Egypt|Canda|German','Pakistan|Saudia|America'),
 (12099,2012,121, 'China|Italy|America','Holanda|Saudia|America')
```

Comment: The `stick` character `|` is called as `pipe`. One can split the string, what would you like to do with the data later on?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have violated 1NF by storing multiple values in a single tuple. You are going to have to parse this into rows. You can use the built in [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)for this.

```
select *
from #countriesData c
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(c.countries, '|') x
```

Comment: i updated post i need to make same thing that i make for column countries for two columns countries and countries2

Comment: Your table design is so utterly broken. Just take the query I posted above with one of your delimited columns. Then use UNION ALL to combine that with a second query that uses the second of your delimited columns. Then go back and fix your table structure and stop storing delimited data like this.